# How to convert the HTML part of a PHP file to PDF?

Tags: php, html, pdf

I've seen .HTML to .PDF using PHP, but not .PHP to .PDF

What I want to do is to convert the HTML part of a PHP file to a PDF file. The reason why I need it to be PHP is because I'm supplying most of the data of the HTML part via PHP

Comment: The php generates html, right? Then convert to PDF

Comment: Do u want to get your php code as a pdf?

Comment: Why don't you open up the page using your browser and print the page as pdf?

Comment: Well, it's part of the requirement that my system "allows them to generate a PDF"

Comment: How do I convert the HTML portion of the PHP file into HTML using codes and not manually copy pasting it into another file

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server-side. You can't convert it to PDF. You can convert result of your PHP script.

Anyway, surely the HTML you get as a result is in a variable (in your PHP script) or you can save it in it. You can then convert the contents of the variable into a PDF using a pdf converter.

Comment: So I need to save my current .PHP state to .HTML, then convert it? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use external php  libraries which converts html (generated from your php script) to pdf like pdfcrowd, mpdf etc..

Comment: Generated you mean I need to literally generate a .HTML file, or generated via the HTML part of a .PHP file? *my php file also contains the html